# Inject property with value from another property of another registered object?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dryioc

I'm not so sure that DryIoc is worth my time. It looks like lightweight and supported well in cross-platform environment (with Xamarin). But I feel a bit difficult working with it (in term of exploring everything myself).

The DryIoc community is also not very large (and by reading through some answers about DryIoc, I recognized that looks like there is only the author jumping in and giving the answers). Here is my problem as mentioned in the title. Suppose I have 2 ViewModel classes, the second has a property which should always match (mapped) with a property of the first, like this:

```
public class ParentViewModel {
}
public class FirstViewModel {
   public FirstViewModel(ParentViewModel parent){
   }
   public string A {
      //...
   }
}
public class SecondViewModel {
   public SecondViewModel(ParentViewModel parent){
   }
   public string A {
      //...
   }
}
```

Now I can use dryioc to register singleton for both ViewModels BUT for the second one, I also need to inject the property A with value from the first's property A as well.

```
container.Register<ParentViewModel>();
container.Register<FirstViewModel>(reuse: Reuse.Singleton, made: Made.Of(() => new FirstViewModel(Arg.Of<ParentViewModel>())));
container.Register<SecondViewModel>(reuse: Reuse.Singleton, made: Made.Of(() => new SecondViewModel(Arg.Of<ParentViewModel>())));
```

So as you can see the first registration should be fine because no property dependency is required. However the second one should have its `A` property depend on the `A` of the first one.

Really I cannot explore this myself. Injecting properties ***of some registered type*** is fine (and at least I know how to do that), but here the injected value is ***another property of some registered type***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [straightforward way](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pQKDQi) (but may be not the best one) to achieve that:

```
using System;
using DryIoc;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Register<ParentViewModel>();

        container.Register<FirstViewModel>(Reuse.Singleton);

        container.Register<SecondViewModel>(Reuse.Singleton, 
            made: PropertiesAndFields.Of.Name("A", r => r.Container.Resolve<FirstViewModel>().A));

        var firstVM = container.Resolve<FirstViewModel>();
        firstVM.A = "blah";

        var secondVM = container.Resolve<SecondViewModel>();

        Console.WriteLine(secondVM.A); // should output "blah"
    }

    public class ParentViewModel {
    }

    public class FirstViewModel {
       public FirstViewModel(ParentViewModel parent) { }
       public string A { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondViewModel {
       public SecondViewModel(ParentViewModel parent) {}
       public string A { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the better and more simple way will the inversion of control: creating the `A` outside of both VMs and then injecting them into both.

Comment: Thank you so much. For your better suggestion at the end, do you think that it is suitable for dynamic content (the `A`) which can be changed at runtime at any time? Does that mean that we need to inject it every time it changes? Anyway that sounds really a better solution to me, I'm not very familiar with IoC in general, so what I thought is setting up everything ***initially***, not in the middle of some process, so maybe that's why I did not think of the solution you suggested at first.

Comment: Simple, if it a dynamic property, just pass it to a method normally. Don't inject.

Comment: I think it's a scenario of mapping property in this case (so that it's auto). Doing (setting it) manually would require you to remember to set it each time you create the VMs. In fact this could be easy if you organize the VMs in tree (so one property can be referenced to another in the same tree easily, or even I do not need different hubs referencing the same object in such a tree, just one is enough. But really I feel that building such a tree is not loosely coupling and testing the VMs may be harder.